# MediaRecorder start failing

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I get `start failed: -19` when I try to run the following code, I am pretty sure I have all the elements I need to begin video capture, I have a surfaceview which I set camera preview to and below is the rest of code that is initialized in

```
   @Override
    public void surfaceCreated( SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder )
```

I constantly get `E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19` when trying to run the method that starts the recorder. Is there something else I need to add before starting the actual recorder?

```
    if(mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.unlock();
     }

    if(mRecorder == null)
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    try {
        mRecorder.setCamera( mCamera );
        mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        //AUDIO
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        //VIDEO
        mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate( 15 );
        
       
        mRecorder.setOutputFile( createNewFile() );
        mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay( mHolder.getSurface() );
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000);
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e( getString( R.string.app_name ), "failed to open Camera" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then in a button click method I have `mRecorder.prepare();mRecorder.start();`.

## Edit

Now I am constantly getting this error when I try to start the recorder  `E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -2147483648` after setting the video encoder before setting the size.

Another observation, do I have to call `startPreview()` on the camera object before starting the recorder?

Answer (score 1):

There a few things that are wrong or missing:

1. `mCamera.unlock()` is missing. This has to be done before you set the camera in Media Recorder.
2. You have to set the video encoder before you set the video size.
3. `mRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 460)` will not work on most devices. Assuming you want to set VGA format it would be `mRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480)` but this assumes that the camera supports video in VGA format. Most cameras do but not all. To find out what video size is supported you need to check `mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes()` and in case that this function returns a null pointer you need to check `mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes()`.

Comment: I will try those adjustments

Comment: I have changed the order as you said but now ` E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -2147483648` error is being thrown.

Comment: Did you check that 640x480 is among the supported video sizes?

Comment: I actually commented out the size, and the recorder still fails

Comment: This does not work on many devices, you have to set the size. I would recommend you either check the supported video sizes or take the size of the preview by using mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize() AFTER you have set the surface holder of the preview display in the camera.

Comment: And btw. on which device are you testing your software? This is an extremely hardware dependant topic.

Comment: I am testing on a Nexus 5 device.